# Neo4j Cypher Count displaying nodes, not relationships pairs Or Union Sets

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My query is:

```
MATCH (n)-[:NT]->(p)
WHERE ...some properties filters...
RETURN n,p
```

The result is on the screenshot below.

**How to count the total nodes?**

I need 14 as a text result. Something like RETURN COUNT(n)+COUNT(p) but it shows 24.

The following request doesn't work correctly:

```
MATCH (n)-[:NT]->(p)
WHERE ...some properties filters...
RETURN count(n)
```

Returns me 12, which is the number of relationships pairs as on the picture, not nodes.

```
MATCH (n)-[:NT]-(p)
WHERE ...some properties filters...
RETURN count(n)
```

Returns 24.

How to count toward that two nodes (in this example) that have outgoing ONLY arrows? Should be 14 at once.

[image: my example]

**UPD:**

```
MATCH (n)-[:NT]->(p)
WHERE ...
RETURN DISTINCT FILTER(x in n.myID WHERE NOT x in p.myID)


MATCH (n)-[:NT]->(p)
WHERE ...
RETURN DISTINCT FILTER(x in p.myID WHERE NOT x in n.myID)
```

The COUNT of DISTINCT UNION of myID gives me the result.
I don't know how to make it with cypher.

Or the DISTINCT UNION of collections:

```
MATCH (n)-[:NT]->(p)
WHERE ...
RETURN collect(DISTINCT p.myID), collect(DISTINCT n.myID)
```

The result is:

```
collect(DISTINCT p.myID)

26375, 26400, 21636, 29939, 20454, 26543, 19089, 4483, 26607, 30375, 26608, 26605

collect(DISTINCT n.myID)

11977, 19478, 20454
```

Which is 15 items. One is common. If you UNION or DISTINCT the `20454` the total COUNT would be 14. The actual number of nodes on the picture.

I can not achieve this simple pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MATCH (n)-[:NT]->(p)
WHERE ...some properties filters...
WITH collect(DISTINCT p.myID) AS set1
MATCH (n)-[:NT]->(p)
WHERE ...some properties filters...
WITH collect(DISTINCT n.myID) AS set2, set1
WITH set1 + set2 AS BOTH
UNWIND BOTH AS res
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your original queries are working correctly.

If you want to get a count of **distinct** `n` nodes, your queries should `RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT n)`.

To count the number of nodes that only have outgoing relationships:

```
MATCH (n)-->()
WHERE NOT ()-->(n)
COUNT(DISTINCT n);
```

To count the number of distinct nodes that are directly involved in an `:NT` relationship:

```
MATCH (n)-[:NT]-()
COUNT(DISTINCT n);
```

Comment: Does not work for me. The result is 3.Please, read the update.

Comment: Also, are you saying that the query at the bottom of my answer returns 3? Can you create a console (http://console.neo4j.org/) that shows the problem?

Comment: I probably did not explain clearly. Please, read it once again. I need something like RETURN COUNT(n,p) meaning n + p as a result which is number of circles on the picture.

Comment: Is the new query added to the bottom of my answer closer to what you are looking for?

Comment: No, sorry. MATCH should contain only [:NT] relation in my case. This is very important. RT relationships could appear in results but I don't pay attention on them.

Comment: OK, I've modified my answer to only look for `NT` relationships. If that is still not what you are looking for, then you'll need to be clearer.

Comment: Seems this one is not that simple. I intentionally marked (p) node, because of some important properties omitted in WHERE clause. No, does not work. I'm trying to collect and count them by IDs. No success. Cypher is not so advanced as SQL scripts.

Comment: Finally I posted my answer that works. Thanks anyway.